# Connecting a Raspberry Pi through Ethernet connection and accesing to its files

Tags: networking, ethernet, raspberrypi

I'm trying to connect to a Raspberry Pi through an Ethernet connection. I see the connection by using ifconfig, but I don't know if there is any way I can access the files in it (I'm trying to set up the wireless connection, but first I have to set up some files, and the access to a monitor is a bit limited to me right now).

Comment: Does the Pi have SSH installed and configured? If not, that's where I'd begin.

Comment: Are you using the Raspberry Pi OS? If so which version? Please [update your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1310235/edit) and add the new information.

Comment: @KGIII the problem is that I cannot set up the ssh of the raspberry because I don't have a monitor for it

Comment: Please provide OS & release details, `ifconfig` is a depreciated tool which may not exist on your system if you're using a modern release.  Please provide your OS & release details so we know what you're using.  (also if you installed a server or desktop system will control the packages pre-instlaled, and whether or not you can `ssh` into it if no changes are made).

Comment: @guiverc I don't know which is the OS & release details because this raspbertty was given to me with everything already installed

Comment: `lsb_release -a` should provide details (multiple lines).  You can add that detail to your question, as the OS &release details do influence the best way to do things (sometimes the only way too)

Comment: @guiverc but the problem is that I cannot write commands to the raspberry. I'm trying to connect it via Ethernet, trying to see if there is any way to establish connection via Ethernet without SSH connection

Comment: We can't really know is available on your PI image until we know what OS & release it is running.  Yes there are alternatives, but we cannot know if they're available to you, or need installation until we know what you're running.  (*let alone Ubuntu has two product streams, with different default packages... thus different commands that add packages... We can't provide commands to install things until we know which Ubuntu system you're using*..)

Comment: @guiverc I mean, it should be a recent version of the most usual OS on raspberry. I can try to obtain the operating system of the raspberry from my supervisor, but until that, this is all the information I can give, because I don't have more

Comment: @guiverc in my computer I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, but I guess what you are referring in the brackets of the last comment is the one of the Raspberry PI

Comment: Ubuntu Core 20 uses different [*package*] commands to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for example; as Ubuntu Core 20 is based on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, the release date varies very little. Recent version of what?  and what do you class as recent?  (days? weeks? months? etc)